# Probability that random nonnegative integer matrix is singular

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices

> ***Q***. What is the probability that an $n \times n$ matrix, whose elements
>   are independent uniformly random integers in $\{0,1,\ldots,k\}$, is singular?

For example, for $n=3$ and $k=2$, the first matrix below is singular and
the second nonsingular:
$$
\left|
       \begin{array}{ccc}
        2 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
       \end{array}
\right| = 0 \;,
$$
$$
\left|
       \begin{array}{ccc}
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 \\
       \end{array}
\right| = 4 \;.
$$
For $n=3$ and $k=1,2,...,14$, 
the probabilities that the matrices are singular are $338/512 = 66.0\%,$ $6891/19683 = 35.0\%,$ $49246/(4^9) = 18.8\%,$ $228737/(5^9) = 11.7\%,$ $716214/(6^9) =7.11\%,$ $... 259500567/(15^9) = 0.675\%$. See [A059976](https://oeis.org/A059976).

I find experimentally that for $n=5$ and $k=2$, about 20.8% are singular.
For $n=5$ and $k=10$, about .07% are singular.
Here is a graph for $n=3$:

---

[image: Singular]

---

Can results for these $(n,k)$-cases be derived from analogous results, e.g.,

> Tao, Terence, and Van Vu. "On random $\pm 1$ matrices: Singularity and determinant." *Random Structures & Algorithms* 28.1 (2006): 1-23. 
>   ([arXiv abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411095).)
>
> Voigt, Thomas, and Günter M. Ziegler. "Singular 0/1-matrices, and the hyperplanes spanned by random 0/1-vectors." *Combinatorics, Probability and Computing* 15.03 (2006): 463-471.
>   ([Cambridge link](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=425840&fileId=S0963548305007339).)
>   ([PDF download pre-publication version](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.226.9930&rep=rep1&type=pdf).)

?

Comment: For fixed $n$ and large $k$, the probability is known to go to zero.  See for example this paper of Martin and Wong which contains more references: https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/AAIMHNIE.pdf .  Also, the work of Rudelson and Vershynin http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703503.pdf which gives very general situations where the probability goes to zero.

Comment: While mathematically distinct from your problem, you can get a feel for the probability through an example like this: Given n randomly chosen vectors in {0,...,k}^n viewed as a cubic lattice, what is the likely hood that all n land on a face of the cube (the jth component has all 0 or all k for the n vectors)?

Comment: It has been conjectured that the probability that an $n\times n$ $\pm 1$ matrix $M$ is singular is asymptotic to the probability that two rows or columns of $M$ are equal up to sign (which is easy to compute). See http://users.uoa.gr/~apgiannop/matrices/Kahn_Komlos_Szemeredi_1995.pdf. Perhaps an analogue holds for matrices with entries $0,1,\dots,k$, e.g., two rows or columns being linearly dependent.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Thanks, Douglas, for finding A059976 and other significant improvements to the question.

Comment: Corollary 1.2 of Bourgain-Vu-Wood http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0461.pdf gives an upper bound of $(1 / \sqrt{k+1}+o(1))^n$ in the regime where $k$ is fixed and $n$ goes to infinity. This can be compared with the trivial lower bound of $(1/(k+1))^n$, coming from the event that the first two rows (say) agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the situation where $n$ is fixed, and $k$ is large, an asymptotic formula for this probability was found by [Yonatan Katznelson](http://www.projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077293427).  From Theorem 1 of his paper (taking there ${\mathcal B}$ to be the box $[0,1]^{n^2}$) the chance of being singular is 
$$ 
\sim C \frac{\log k}{k^n}, 
$$
for a constant $C$.  Katznelson considers more generally singular matrices with integer entries lying in a large dilate of a fixed region ${\mathcal B}$ in ${\Bbb R}^{n^2}$ (the box $[0,1]^{n^2}$ being the example of this question).  His asymptotic is a little different from an earlier result (the difference is the $\log k$ factor) of [Duke, Rudnick, and Sarnak](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/euclid.dmj/1077289840) who counted such matrices with a given non-zero determinant. Other references, dealing with variants of this problem, or in the regime where $k$ is fixed and $n$ is large may be found in the comments.